# How to round a data.frame in R that contains some character variables?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, and I wish to round all of the numbers (ready for export).  This must be straightforward, but I am having problems because some bits of the dataframe are not numeric numbers.  For example I want to round the figures to the nearest whole number in the example below:

```
ID = c("a","b","c","d","e")
Value1 = c("3.4","6.4","8.7","1.1","0.1")
Value2 = c("8.2","1.7","6.4","1.9","10.3")
df<-data.frame(ID,Value1,Value2)
```

Can anyone help me out?  I can round individual columns (e.g., `round(df$Value1, 2)`) but I want to round a whole table which contains some columns which are not numeric.

Comment: Rounding makes sense for "numbers", not characters. You'll have to convert `Value1` and `Value2` as `numeric`, e.g. `round(as.numeric(Value1), 0)` would do the job, but you didn't specify how rounding should be done (lookup for one of `trunc`, `ceiling`, or `floor`).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First make sure your number columns are numeric:

```
ID = c("a","b","c","d","e")
Value1 = as.numeric(c("3.4","6.4","8.7","1.1","0.1"))
Value2 = as.numeric(c("8.2","1.7","6.4","1.9","10.3"))
df<-data.frame(ID,Value1,Value2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then, round only the numeric columns:

```
df[,-1] <-round(df[,-1],0) #the "-1" excludes column 1
df

  ID Value1 Value2
1  a      3      8
2  b      6      2
3  c      9      6
4  d      1      2
5  e      0     10
```

Comment: Simple and efficient :)

Answer (score 127):

I think the neatest way of doing this now is using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 mutate_if(is.numeric, round)
```

This will round all numeric columns in your dataframe

Comment: Brilliant! `library(dplyr); df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits=3)`

Comment: `mutate_if` has been superseded by `across` ! now use `library(dplyr); df %>% mutate(across(is.numeric, round, digits=3))`

Comment: `df %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, digits=3))`

Answer (score 57):

Recognizing that this is an old question and one answer is accepted, I would like to offer another solution since the question appears as a top-ranked result on Google.

A more general solution is to create a separate function that searches for **all numerical variables** and rounds them to the specified number of digits:

```
round_df <- function(df, digits) {
  nums <- vapply(df, is.numeric, FUN.VALUE = logical(1))

  df[,nums] <- round(df[,nums], digits = digits)

  (df)
}
```

Once defined, you can use it as follows:

```
> round_df(df, digits=3)
```

Comment: brilliant, simple solution that I never would have thought of! Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

I know this is a late reply, but I also had this same problem. After doing some searching I found this to be the most elegant solution:

```
data.frame(lapply(x, function(y) if(is.numeric(y)) round(y, 2) else y))
```

Solution originally from:
Jean V. Adams 
Statistician 
U.S. Geological Survey 
Great Lakes Science Center 
223 East Steinfest Road 
Antigo, WI 54409  USA

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/round-a-data-frame-containing-character-variables-td3732415.html

Comment: This is a standard solution.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a one-liner that I like using:
(this will apply the `round` function to only the columns of class type specified in the `classes` argument)

```
df2 <- rapply(object = df, f = round, classes = "numeric", how = "replace", digits = 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers do not quite answer the OP's question exactly because they assume the example data is different from what the OP has provided.

If we read the question literally, and we want a general solution that will find columns with digits in them (of any vector type), convert them to numeric, and then perform another numeric operation, such as rounding. We can use `purrr:dmap` and do it like this:

Here's the data as provided by the OP, where all cols are factors (an annoying default, but we can deal with it):

```
ID = c("a","b","c","d","e")
Value1 = c("3.4","6.4","8.7","1.1","0.1")
Value2 = c("8.2","1.7","6.4","1.9","10.3")
df<-data.frame(ID,Value1,Value2)

str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ID    : Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ Value1: Factor w/ 5 levels "0.1","1.1","3.4",..: 3 4 5 2 1
 $ Value2: Factor w/ 5 levels "1.7","1.9","10.3",..: 5 1 4 2 3
```

We'll search for cols with digits in them, and make a dataframe of indices to mark the numerics:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df_logical <- 
df %>% 
  dmap(function(i) grepl("[0-9]", i))

df_logical
     ID Value1 Value2
1 FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
2 FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
3 FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
4 FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
5 FALSE   TRUE   TRUE

str(df_logical)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ID    : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ Value1: logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 $ Value2: logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Then we can use these indices to select a subset of the cols in the original dataframe and convert them to numeric, and do other things also (in this case, rounding):

```
df_numerics <- 
map(1:ncol(df), function(i) ifelse(df_logical[,i], 
                                      as.numeric(as.character(df[,i])), 
                                      df[,i])) %>% 
  dmap(round, 0) %>% 
  setNames(names(df))
```

And we've got the desired result:

```
df_numerics
  ID Value1 Value2
1  1      3      8
2  2      6      2
3  3      9      6
4  4      1      2
5  5      0     10

str(df_numerics)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ID    : num  1 2 3 4 5
 $ Value1: num  3 6 9 1 0
 $ Value2: num  8 2 6 2 10
```

This could be useful in the case of a dataframe with a large number of columns, and where we have many character/factor type cols full of digits that we want as numeric, but it's too tedious to do by hand.

Answer (score 3):

The answers above point out a couple of stumbling blocks in the initial question, that make it more complicated than just rounding multiple columns, primarily:

1. Numbers were entered as characters, and
2. `data.frame()` default converts the character-numbers to factors

The response by Ben details how to handle these issues, and applies `purrr::dmap()`. The `purrr` package has since been modified and the `dmap` function is deprecated (in favor of `map_df()`).
There is also a newer function, `modify_if()` which can solve the problem of rounding multiple numeric columns, and so I wanted to update this answer.

---

I'll enter the data as numbers, adding a few more digits to round to make the example more broadly applicable:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("a","b","c","d","e"), 
                 Value1 =c(3.4532897,6.41325,8.71235,1.115,0.115), 
                 Value2 = c(8.2125,1.71235,6.4135,1.915,10.3235))
```

Using the `purrr::modify_if()` function:

```
purrr::modify_if(df, ~is.numeric(.), ~round(., 0))

  ID Value1 Value2
1  a      3      8
2  b      6      2
3  c      9      6
4  d      1      2
5  e      0     10
```

just change to `round(digits= 0)` to the appropriate decimal spaces

```
modify_if(df, ~is.numeric(.), ~round(., 2))
  ID Value1 Value2
1  a   3.45   8.21
2  b   6.41   1.71
3  c   8.71   6.41
4  d   1.12   1.92
5  e   0.12  10.32
```

see http://purrr.tidyverse.org/ for further documentation on syntax

This could also be done in two steps using base R apply functions, by creating an index for the columns (numVars) and then standard indexing to modify only those columns:

```
numVars <-  sapply(df, is.numeric)
   ID Value1 Value2 
FALSE   TRUE   TRUE 

df[, numVars] <- lapply(df[, numVars], round, 0)
df
  ID Value1 Value2
1  a      3      8
2  b      6      2
3  c      9      6
4  d      1      2
5  e      0     10
```

Comment: note that `numVars <- apply(df, 2, is.numeric)` fails, because it coerces the dataframe into a matrix (converts all columns to the same type- character). `sapply()` does not do this.

Comment: modify if seems not to exist in current purrr package. I get errors saying not found modify_if after downloading and loading the purrr package

Comment: @Mark hmmm...I just checked and it is in the current CRAN version (purrr 0.2.3). I edited slightly the command so it is `purrr::modify_if` so that you don't have to load the package. see if that helps.

Comment: @Mark it also looks like it is in the current Github verson. However, the tidyverse is changing so much right now that I'm sticking mostly with CRAN for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Note that some solutions proposed above do not take care of row names, meaning that they got lost.

For example, try:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = seq(1.11, 1.20, 0.01), v2 = letters[1:10])
row.names(df) = df$v2
```

and then, as suggested above, try:

```
data.frame( lapply(df, function(y) if(is.numeric(y)) round(y, 2) else y) )
```

Note that the row names are no longer there.

Akhmed's suggestion keeps row names because it works with replacements.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative. This function makes it easy to specify the actual rounding function and accepts unique digits value for each column:

```
rounddf <- function(x, digits = rep(2, ncol(x)), func = round) {
  if (length(digits) == 1) {
    digits <- rep(digits, ncol(x))
  } else if (length(digits) != ncol(x)) {
    digits <- c(digits, rep(digits[1], ncol(x) - length(digits)))
    warning('First value in digits repeated to match length.')
  }

  for(i in 1:ncol(x)) {
    if(class(x[, i])[1] == 'numeric') x[, i] <- func(x[, i], digits[i])
  }

  return(x)
}
```

It's posted (and sometimes updated) at https://github.com/sashahafner/jumbled

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use ID as the row name?

... and take out the "'s from value1 and value2 data

Try this instead:

```
ID = c("a","b","c","d","e")
Value1 = c(3.4,6.4,8.7,1.1,0.1)
Value2 = c(8.2,1.7,6.4,1.9,10.3)

df<-data.frame(ID,Value1,Value2,row.names=TRUE)

> df
  Value1 Value2
a    3.4    8.2
b    6.4    1.7
c    8.7    6.4
d    1.1    1.9
e    0.1   10.3

> str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Value1: num  3.4 6.4 8.7 1.1 0.1
 $ Value2: num  8.2 1.7 6.4 1.9 10.3
```

I am not sure what you want to do with the round, but you have some options in R:

```
?ceiling()
?floor()
?trunc()
```

Comment: In the case you know which columns you want to round and have converted, you can also do `df[,c('Value1','Value2')] <- round(as.numeric(df[,c('Value1','Value2')]))` (this might be desirable if there are many text columns but only a few that can be made numeric).

Comment: Additionally, if you want to  seek out just numeric columns and round you could use `df[,sapply(df, is.numeric)] <-round(df[,sapply(df, is.numeric)],0)`

Comment: Thanks Tyler! This was exactly what I was looking for - you saved my lots of time!!