# Is there a vectorized way to use is.numeric?

Tags: r, vectorization

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063889/rounding-a-dataframe-in-r) at SO and was wondering if there is any way to use is.numeric in a vectorized way. The point being, if you have a vectorized way to check if a variable is numeric, then any function what depends on the variable being numeric can be vectorized. Otherwise, it cannot be vectorized.

Comment: `is.numeric` is vectorized... can you give an example of what you're thinking about?

Comment: I assume that the questioner is thinking `is.numeric(1:5)` should give a vector of TRUE 5 long rather than a single TRUE.  so something like `sapply(1:5,is.numeric)`

Comment: @Justin: ah, then the answer is "no".  You can't mix types in an atomic vector, so it would be redundant to return a `TRUE` or `FALSE` value for every element in the vector.  You can mix types in a list (which is what a data.frame is), and that's where you should use your `sapply` solution.

Comment: Roger that.  I was just trying to understand his question.

Comment: yep, I was thinking of a data.frame and how to get which columns are numeric or nor, for example. It seems that I should use any suitable function of the apply family...

Comment: @Justin Seems like you should write up your comment as an Answer then Manoel can accept it and this one can be closed out, whilst you get a bit of rep in the process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the comments:

if you're looking to test columns of a data.frame with as.numeric, use `sapply` or `lapply` (but not `apply`)

```
dat <- data.frame(v1=1:5,v2=letters[1:5],v3=rnorm(5),v4=c(1,2,'c','d',5))

sapply(dat,is.numeric)
#   v1    v2    v3    v4 
# TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or, for variety, you can use `colwise` from the plyr package:

```
library(dplyr)  # since pkg:plyr is now deprecated
colwise(is.numeric)(dat)
#    v1    v2   v3    v4
#1 TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: The `plyr` package has a `numcolwise` function that automatically can apply any function to the numerical columns in a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

This should give the desired result:

```
rep(is.numeric(x), length(x))
```

Comment: However, given a mixed list: `x<-list('a',2,'c',4)` this will yield a vector of all `FALSE` since `is.numeric(x)` is `FALSE`.  `lapply(x,is.numeric)` gives the expected results.

Comment: @Justin: I was expecting the input to be a single "variable" which I took to be an atomic vector. For different interpretations of the wording of hte question your method might (l)apply.

Comment: Doesn't work with alphanumeric with numeric inside. In this case see `!is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(c("1","a",3,"",5.3))))` ->`TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE` there [Checking if vector components are numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35924734/10489562).

Comment: @phili_b There are multiple possible meanings of the word "variable". My interpretation was that the person had a dataframe and wanted to know which of the columns were numeric. Other people interpreted it to mean something along the lines of ::: "Given an atomic vector containing character values, which of these items in that vector can be successfully coerced to numeric values, presumably using `as.numeric`?". FWIW; The accepted answer agrees with my interpretation.

Comment: You're right. The normal way is normal numeric, my point was I've searched a moment to understand, so my comment, the  exception case of non vectorization  of  `is.numeric()` despite that quasi of  all R functions are vectorized, and strange return values of it. Funny to speak about that over more than 10 years after   :)