# Checking if vector components are numeric

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector

```
x <- c('a', 'b', 1, 2)
```

What is the easiest way for me to get an output that indicates whether or not the components of `x` are numeric? I.e., the output should be

```
something(x) 

[1] FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

The way I know how to do this is to convert `x` to a matrix and use `apply`:

```
apply(as.matrix(x), FUN = is.numeric, MARGIN = 1)
```

But after testing, this actually doesn't work - I forgot that the types are coerced to become strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `is.na` and `as.numeric`

```
!is.na(as.numeric(x))
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

with a friendly warning

Or use `grep` to match only numeric elements from start (`^`) to end (`$`)

```
grepl("^-?[0-9.]+$", x)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: It works also with alphanumeric with numeric inside: `!is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(c("1","a",3,"",5.3))))` ->`TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE`  (At the opposite of some others solutions which work only with type numeric.