# is.numeric within apply vs sapply

Tags: r

In writing R code to identify columns with numeric data, I had some issues and found this question on SO:  [Is there a vectorized way to use is.numeric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065545/is-there-a-vectorized-way-to-use-is-numeric)

Within that page I found my answer, but I'm puzzled by the nature of the problem itself.  On that page, the following code snip does what I expect:

```
> dat <- data.frame(v1=1:5,v2=letters[1:5],v3=rnorm(5),v4=c(1,2,'c','d',5))

> sapply(dat,is.numeric)

   v1    v2    v3    v4 
 TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

But if I change sapply to apply, I get to what caused my problem.

```
> dat <- data.frame(v1=1:5,v2=letters[1:5],v3=rnorm(5),v4=c(1,2,'c','d',5))

> apply(dat,2,is.numeric)

   v1    v2    v3    v4 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Why do apply and sapply result in different evaluations?

Comment: `help(apply)` - *If `X` is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array via `as.matrix` if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via `as.array`.*

Comment: `apply` and `lapply` are different functions, so no wonder they give different results. Be aware of fully understand what they do and when they should be used.

Comment: @RichardScriven - thank you for that detail.  I did not see that bit in the apply - clearly I overlooked it or didn't appreciate it in the right context.  I would upvote or accept you're answer if I could.

Comment: @nicola - I don't recall mentioning lapply anywhere in my question, but yes, it is different from apply.

Comment: @KirkDCO You did, since `sapply` is just a wrapper of `lapply` which "prettifies" the output. If `lapply` is different from `apply` so is `sapply`. No wonder you get different outputs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`apply` coerces everything into the same type. Numbers can become characters but not vice versa. So everything is coerced to `character` for apply to work.

```
> apply(dat[,1, drop = F], 2, is.numeric)
  v1 
TRUE
```

Comment: The rules of coercion are listed out in this answer if anyone is interested - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030173/why-does-hello-0-return-true/17030209#17030209 - `character > complex > numeric > integer > logical > raw`

Answer (score 4):

`apply` is not advisable for data frames as it will coerce to a matrix. Matrix,as you probably are aware all columns in a matrix must have the same mode(numeric, character, etc.)... by default `apply` converts the columns into character.