# R format decimal places of result in table

Tags: r, decimal, rounding, mean

I would like to round the output to one decimal place in mean table

```
aov_two <- aov(Mass ~ Distance + Colony + Distance:Colony, data = seed_ant)
summary(aov_two)
B <- model.tables(aov_two, "means")
```

model table of mean result is,

> B
>       Tables of means
>       Grand mean

```
54.2461 

Distance 
     0      5     10
 56.53  53.19  52.25
```

rep 221.00 217.00 139.00

```
Colony 
  101     2    23    25    28     3     4     X
64.91 41.84 51.44 60.55 50.83 45.32 54.25 60.85
```

rep 82.00 71.00 52.00 76.00 59.00 77.00 75.00 85.00

```
Distance:Colony 
    Colony
Distance 101   2     23    25    28    3     4     X    
 0   61.79 41.04 51.97 74.52 53.45 41.33 53.26 72.04
 rep 29.00 24.00 29.00 29.00 29.00 27.00 27.00 27.00
 5   70.33 40.45 52.61 55.20 49.47 47.75 54.18 57.15
 rep 27.00 29.00 23.00 25.00 30.00 28.00 28.00 27.00
 10  62.23 44.50       48.05       46.59 55.30 53.42
 rep 26.00 18.00  0.00 22.00  0.00 22.00 20.00 31.00
```

how can I round all those numbers to one decimal place?

Comment: Does this link answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063889/rounding-a-dataframe-in-r?

Answer (score 0):

It's rather difficult to read the `data.frame`s in your question, but try:

```
df <- round(df, 1)
```