# Rounding numbers in a dataframe with mixed values (string, date, number, etc.)

Tags: r, dataframe, rounding

I have been trying to round numbers in a dataframe with multiple values, but cannot figure out a way. Tried to set `options(digits = 6)`, solutions offered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063889/how-to-round-a-data-frame-in-r-that-contains-some-character-variables) topic, and some others. My dataframe looks like:

```
structure(list(X__1 = c("Start", "End", "EFM", "UTH", "PEU", 
"HPX"), `TecM` = c("Mar-00", "Mar-01", "NA", "NA", 
"-9.6432560109885879E-2", "-0.26834090581750103"), `TerA` = c("Sep-01", 
"Sep-01", "NA", "NA", "0", "-0.11600490599886504"), `GloC` = c("Nov-07", 
"Mar-09", "-0.62921737727223548", "NA", "-0.54549924666990268", 
"-0.54518556256613238"), `ECis` = c("Jul-11", 
"Sep-11", "-0.2912541254125412", "NA", "-0.21781440969547586", 
"-0.18769305803934319"), `OSe` = c("Jul-14", "Dec-14", 
"-0.10996326905417812", "-3.4236420002695674E-2", "-2.8281230134625412E-2", 
"4.8566639665387892E-2")), .Names = c("X__1", "TecM", 
"TerA", "GloC", "ECis", 
"Oil Selloff"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Are there any simple options?

Comment: Well, all your columns are characters. So although they look like numbers/date  in there, they are still treated as characters. You need to round them before they get into dataframe.

Comment: @RonakShah, these are coming from an Excel file, so I have no control over the data...

Comment: Haha, no, this cannot be done. Some strings are long.

Comment: It's not a proper `data.frame`. I would suggest reashaping it ( basicly transpose).

Comment: @AK88 did one of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there is also a `tibble` solution, but I'm always getting confused on selecting columns etc in `tibbles`. That's why I changed it into a `data.frame`.

```
jnk1 <- as.data.frame(jnk)
numeric_values <- !is.na(apply(jnk1, 2, as.numeric))
jnk1[numeric_values] <- round(as.numeric(jnk1[numeric_values]),1)
```

Imagine your data is called `ink`. Save it as a `data.frame`. Check which values could be parsed into numeric and then overwrite them by the round value.

Since there might be warnings, u can suppress them with this line

```
numeric_values <- suppressWarnings(!is.na(apply(jnk1, 2, as.numeric)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just for easier *viewing*, the following line will round all numeric-looking values in the table to 2 digits:

```
# assume df is your original data frame
suppressWarnings(data.frame(lapply(df, function(y) ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(y)), y, round(as.numeric(y), 2)))))

# result
   X__1   TecM   TerA   GloC   ECis Oil.Selloff
1 Start Mar-00 Sep-01 Nov-07 Jul-11      Jul-14
2   End Mar-01 Sep-01 Mar-09 Sep-11      Dec-14
3   EFM     NA     NA  -0.63  -0.29       -0.11
4   UTH     NA     NA     NA     NA       -0.03
5   PEU   -0.1      0  -0.55  -0.22       -0.03
6   HPX  -0.27  -0.12  -0.55  -0.19        0.05
```

But a column with numeric / string / date in a data frame would still be a column of characters.